# Kali Linux won't connect to wireless network

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I'm dual-booting Windows 8 and Kali Linux. On Linux, my wireless connection doesn't work; it keeps asking for the wifi password but refuses to connect. The same network works fine on Windows 8. Is there some setting I should change to fix this on Linux?

Comment: Include some more details. Are you using network manager or iwconfig? What type of network is it (WPA, Open, WEP)? If it is WPA, do you have wpa_supplicant in use?